# Create a graph on the evolution of the number of shots

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, seaborn

I got a data frame like this :

```
   Team     Time     
8   Red 00:02:31   
10 Blue 00:03:01  
12  Red 00:85:31  
14 Blue 00:87:02  
 ...
```

PS: it represents shots of the match.

I would like to do a graph like that:

[image]

First, is it possible to do this with my df or do I have to change it?
Second, how can I do it?

Comment: What have you tried? Can you share your df code for the data?

Comment: 'matplotlib.pyplot' seems to be the right way to go. Just plot the teams and times using "bar".

Comment: df = pd.DataFrame({
    'Team': ['red', 'red', 'red', 'blue', 'blue', 'blue', 'blue', 'red', 'red', 'blue', 'red', 'blue'],
    'Time': ['1900-01-01 00:09:01', '1900-01-01 00:15:03', '1900-01-01 00:18:04', '1900-01-01 00:33:11',
             '1900-01-01 00:36:12', '1900-01-01 00:57:23', '1900-01-01 01:06:25', '1900-01-01 01:09:26',
             '1900-01-01 01:15:28', '1900-01-01 01:21:31', '1900-01-01 01:24:33', '1900-01-01 01:27:35']},
    index=[4, 8, 10, 20, 22, 36, 42, 44, 48, 52, 54, 56])

Comment: Yeah i tried matplotlib.pyplot.bar but not working :
matplotlib.pyplot.bar(x=butr['Time'],height=['Team'])    
  
I also tried this:
df_grouped = df.groupby(by=['Time', 'Team']).size().reset_index()
df_grouped.rename(columns = {0 : 'Counts'}, inplace = True)
df_grouped.sort_values(['Team'], inplace=True)
colors = ['r', 'g', 'b']
for i, ltr in enumerate(df_grouped.Team.unique()):
    plt.plot(df_grouped[df_grouped.Team == ltr].Time, df_grouped[df_grouped.Team == ltr].Counts, '-o', label=ltr, c=colors[i],)
plt.show()

Comment: I found the last code on this page:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72501156/time-series-plot-showing-unique-occurrences-per-day
But first, it's not a bar graph and second, it doesn't work properly.

Comment: Please, [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/75119982/edit) your post and add missing data and code.  The comments are only meant for short clarifications. Also, try to clearly explain what is  *"not working"*.  You can add code using triple backticks (```).

Answer (score 0):

This might be one way to approach this. Here I used [Seaborn object interface](https://seaborn.pydata.org/tutorial/objects_interface.html), available from v0.12.

```py
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
import seaborn.objects as so
import matplotlib as mpl
from matplotlib.dates import MinuteLocator

sns.set_theme()

df_original = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        'Team': ['red', 'red', 'red', 'blue', 'blue', 'blue', 'blue', 'red', 'red', 'blue', 'red', 'blue'],
        'Time': ['1900-01-01 00:09:01', '1900-01-01 00:15:03', '1900-01-01 00:18:04', '1900-01-01 00:33:11', '1900-01-01 00:36:12', '1900-01-01 00:57:23', '1900-01-01 01:06:25', '1900-01-01 01:09:26', '1900-01-01 01:15:28', '1900-01-01 01:21:31', '1900-01-01 01:24:33', '1900-01-01 01:27:35']
    },
    index=[4, 8, 10, 20, 22, 36, 42, 44, 48, 52, 54, 56]
)

df = (df_original
    .assign(Team=df.Team.astype("category"),
            Time=pd.to_datetime(df.Time))
)

(
    so.Plot(df, x="Time", color="Team")

    # Workaround for passing datetime for `bins`
    # c.f. https://github.com/mwaskom/seaborn/issues/2371#issuecomment-768637786
    .add(so.Bar(), so.Hist(bins=mpl.dates.date2num(pd.date_range("1900-01-01", end="1900-01-01 02", freq="5min"))), so.Dodge())

    .scale(
        color=so.Nominal(values=["red", "blue"], order=["red", "blue"]),
        x=so.Temporal().tick(locator=MinuteLocator(interval=5)).label(concise=True),
        y=so.Continuous().tick(every=1)
    )

    # To adjust x-tick to start from `00:00`, shifting start time 10 sec. Hacky :(
    .limit(x=(mpl.dates.date2num(pd.to_datetime("1900-01-01") - pd.to_timedelta(10, unit="S")), None))

    .layout(size=(10, 3))
)
```

[image]